# HDR imaging opencv 3.1 and swift 4.2 image rotate of 90 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, camera

I use swift 4.2 and OpenCV 3.1, I install Opencv with Pod.

So there is my function call in my swift file:

```
image = OpenCVWrapper.hdrImaging(Arrayimages, Arraytimes)
```

- Arrayimages is an array of UIImage
- Arraytimes is an array of Float64

In my **OpencvWrapper.h** I call my function like this:

```
+(UIImage *) hdrImaging:(NSArray *)images :(NSArray *)times;
```

and I make this function in my **OpenCVWrapper.mm**

```
+(UIImage *) hdrImaging:(NSArray *)images :(NSArray *)times{

    cv::Mat response;

    std::vector<cv::Mat> imagesVector;
    std::vector<float> timesVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
        UIImage * imageToMat = images[i];
        cv::Mat rgba, matToInsert;

        UIImageToMat(imageToMat, rgba); // rgba is RGBA
        cv::cvtColor(rgba, matToInsert, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR) // matToInsert is 3 channel BGR        

        imagesVector.push_back(matToInsert);
        float time = [times[i] floatValue];
        timesVector.push_back(time);
    }

    cv::Ptr<cv::CalibrateDebevec> calibrate = cv::createCalibrateDebevec();
    calibrate->process(imagesVector, response, timesVector);
    cv::Mat hdr;
    cv::Ptr<cv::MergeDebevec> merge_debevec = cv::createMergeDebevec();
    merge_debevec->process(imagesVector, hdr, timesVector, response);
    cv::Mat ldr;
    cv::Ptr<cv::TonemapDurand> tonemap = cv::createTonemapDurand(2.2f);
    tonemap->process(hdr, ldr);
    cv::Mat fusion;
    cv::Ptr<cv::MergeMertens> merge_mertens = cv::createMergeMertens();
    merge_mertens->process(imagesVector, fusion);

    response = fusion * 255;
    response.convertTo(response, CV_8U);

    return MatToUIImage(response);
}
```

***EDIT***

If you have a memory error like :

**EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=650 MB, unused=0x0)**
on the line `merge_debevec->process(imagesVector, hdr, timesVector, response);`

You can dows quality of your picture with the following code in your declaration of capture session : `captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1920x1080` or an other résolution!

***EDIT 2***

if you have an error about invalid bits/components :

```
CustomCamera[5793:1463869] [Unknown process name] CGImageCreate: invalid image bits/component: 8 bits/pixel 96 alpha info = kCGImageAlphaNone
```

Don't forget to set your response Mat to 8bit like : `response.convertTo(response, CV_8U);`

Why my picture rotate ? I think is MatToUIImage function who rotate my picture but how to set my picture with the good rotation ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The first error says you ran out of memory, probably due to big size of images. As for the second error, `UIImageToMat` convert `UIImage` to a 4 channel `RGBA` image. So you need to convert that into a `BGR` or `RGB` for HDR,

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
    UIImage * imageToMat = images[i];
    cv::Mat rgba, matToInsert;

    UIImageToMat(imageToMat, rgba); // rgba is RGBA
    cv::cvtColor(rgba, matToInsert, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR) // matToInsert is 3 channel BGR        

    imagesVector.push_back(matToInsert);
    float time = [times[i] floatValue];
    timesVector.push_back(time);
}
```